# How to move a struct's implementation into a separate file without putting it in a submodule?

Tags: rust

I have this main function:

```rust
mod tools;

fn main() {
    let mut factory = tools::TerminalFactory::new();
    let trm: tools::Terminal;

    trm = factory.create("TTY1".to_string());
    println!("{}", trm);

    std::process::exit(0);
}
```

This is `tools/mod.rs`:

```rust
pub struct Terminal {
    id: u32,
    pub name: String
}

impl Terminal {
    pub fn get_id(self: &Self) -> u32 {
        self.id
    }
}

impl std::fmt::Display for Terminal {
    fn fmt(self: &Self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "TERMINAL#{} ({})", self.id, self.name)
    }
}

pub struct TerminalFactory {
    next_id: u32
}

impl TerminalFactory {
    pub fn new() -> TerminalFactory {
        TerminalFactory {
            next_id: 0
        }
    }

    pub fn create(self: &mut Self, name: String) -> Terminal {
        self.next_id += 1;

        Terminal {
            id: self.next_id,
            name: name
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I have two structs in `tools`: `tools::TerminalFactory` and `tools::Terminal`. What I want to do is have those two structs implemented in two separate files, because the `tools` module will be pretty crowded and I don't want to clutter it with thousands of lines of code.

I can't come up with a way to move this code to separate files and keep it in `tools`. What I get when I move it to other files is that in `tools/mod.rs` I have to define the `mod`:

```rust
mod terminal;
mod terminal_factory;
```

But this *moves* the structs to `tools::terminal_factory::TerminalFactory` and `tools::terminal::Terminal`, which is not what I want.

How is this done in a *rustical* way without a `*.toml` and without cargo?

> I will certainly use cargo, but I want to understand beforehand how to do this without it.

Comment: Note that by convention, module names use snake_case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You usually reexport deeper types when you don't want to expose this modular structure.

Here, your tools/mod.rs file would be

```rust
mod terminal;
mod terminal_factory;

pub use {
    self::terminal::Terminal,
    self::terminal_factory::TerminalFactory,
};
```

The `pub use` enables external code to use the `TerminalFactory` type as if it was declared in the upper module.

Comment: I edited this answer because my question was not well defined. I confused the concept of "module" with the constructs defined in a module (like in C#/Java, where you have a "file" concept, a "class" concept and then "one class per file" guideline). From Sven Marnach's comment and the help on rust-lang.org I actually understood the conceptual difference and then realized that my question was not even comprehensible. By using snake_case for modules and CamelCase for structs it's better to understand. And then "one struct per file" is a personal choice, not a guideline...

Comment: I hope this explains why I edited the question and answer and that it is acceptable per SO policy.